# How do I set up Sphinx to work on a database located in a local server?

Tags: xampp, sphinx

I'm using XAMPP to test my web application, and I need to use Sphinx to make some complex queries to a database.

I'm following this guide: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#intro, I managed to follow the steps until: `/usr/local/sphinx/bin/indexer --all`. I get this output: (sphynx.conf is the one provided by default: `sphinx.conf.dist`)

```
Sphinx 2.2.10-id64-release (2c212e0)
Copyright (c) 2001-2015, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2015, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/usr/local/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'test1'...
collected 4 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 4 docs, 193 bytes
total 0.005 sec, 32377 bytes/sec, 671.02 docs/sec
indexing index 'test1stemmed'...
collected 4 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 4 docs, 193 bytes
total 0.001 sec, 110222 bytes/sec, 2284.40 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'dist1'...
skipping non-plain index 'rt'...
total 8 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 24 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

I don't see any errors, so I kept going and tried to test the index using this query: `SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH('my document');`; and I get a SQL syntax error which is weird, then I tried this: `SELECT * from test1 WHERE 1` and I get this: `#1146 - Table 'test.test1' doesn't exist`.
I'm struggling to fix this error, Do you have any idea what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you connect to MySQL instead of Sphinx. Try to execute:

```
SHOW DATABASES;
```

Comment: The output is just ``test``, which is the database I'm working on.